# Only get the XML node with the Specific value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

im doing an Weather Application that works well but i encountered a problem.
The XMl seems like:

```
<city>
  <city_code>DE0011259</city_code>
  <name>Wegberg</name>
  <url>deutschland/wegberg/DE0011259.html</url>
  <post_code>41844</post_code>
  <forecast>
    <date value="2014-12-01">
      <w>2</w>
      <tx>4</tx>
      <pc>30</pc>
      <time value="06:00">
        <w>2</w>
        <tx>3</tx>
        <pc>30</pc>
        <tn>2</tn>
        <ws>11</ws>
        <w_txt>wolkig</w_txt>
      </time>
      <time value="11:00">
        <w>2</w>
        <tx>4</tx>
        <pc>20</pc>
        <tn>3</tn>
        <ws>12</ws>
        <w_txt>wolkig</w_txt>
      </time>
      <time value="17:00">
        <w>2</w>
        <tx>4</tx>
        <pc>20</pc>
        <tn>1</tn>
        <ws>9</ws>
        <w_txt>wolkig</w_txt>
      </time>
      <time value="23:00">
        <w>2</w>
        <tx>1</tx>
        <pc>30</pc>
        <tn>1</tn>
        <ws>7</ws>
        <w_txt>wolkig</w_txt>
      </time>
      <tn>1</tn>
      <ws>10</ws>
      <w_txt>wolkig</w_txt>
    </date>
  </forecast>
</city>
```

Sorry if my english is so bad^^
The question is how i get the data from the other time´s 
My problem is that i only get the data from 6:00 and don´t know how to get the data from 17:00 or 23:00

My code for getting Weather:

```
string xml;
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    xml = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
}
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

string wind = doc.XPathSelectElement("/city/forecast/date/time/ws").Value + " km/h";
```

Comment: Use `XPathSelectElements()`.

Comment: [XPathSelectElemen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: `I don´t know how to say that i wan´t to get the results from other times.` You already get only the first entry. What is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that i only get the data from 6:00 and don´t know how to get the data from 17:00 or 23:00

Seems like you should have a condition in your xpath, for ex.,

```
string wind = doc.XPathSelectElement("/city/forecast/date/time[@value='17:00']/ws")
                 .Value + " km/h";
```

(See *`[@value='17:00']`*)

If you want to get all values then you can use `XPathSelectElement**s**` as said in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is perform a query over your XML *for a specific time*, then it is very easy to get what you want by using `Linq To XML`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"somePath\SO.xml");

// E.g. get ws value for time = "17:00"    
XElement specificElement = doc.Descendants("time")
                              .Where(t => t.Attribute("value").Value == "17:00")
                              .FirstOrDefault();
if (specificElement != null)
{
   string wind = specificElement.Element("ws").Value + " km/h";
}
```

Comment: What is wrong in the question? It can also be done easily by an xpath query as in question.

Comment: @L.B. Well, at least as far as I am concerned, it is not very clear  what the OP wants to do. That's why I used italics in my answer. In case he wants to get the wind velocity for a specific time, then this can easily be done with Linq to XML. An xpath query is also an option.

Comment: Even if i do: specificElement.Element("ws").Value it still gives me the value from 6:00

Comment: @Chakratos That's not possible, I've test the code before posting it. It will work with the xml excerpt you have posted. It will not work if e.g. there are 2 "17:00" hr <time> nodes in the xml and you want to get to the second one. In this case you have to fiddle a little bit with linq.

Comment: Yeah it was my fault, here in Germany it is a new day and the values changed ^^